# Why does setting the position of an external application only work correctly with breakpoint?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to relocate the position of an external application, i.e. On-Screen Keyboard. It only works correctly if I place a breakpoint. If I run it either from VS without the breakpoint or by running the executable, it doesn't function. Why?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;

public void SetWindowPosition(string txtAppTitle, string txtWidth, string txtHeight, string txtX, string txtY)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, txtAppTitle);

    // If found, position it.
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // Move the window to (txtX, txtY) without changing its size.
        int x = int.Parse(txtX);
        int y = int.Parse(txtY);
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
    }
}

private void btnOnScreenKeyboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetWindowPosition("On-Screen Keyboard", "0", "0", "155", "545");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't function? What happens? Any error?

Comment: it doesn't move the On-Screen Keyboard top the tetX,txtY position that I've giving it. The On-Screen Keyboard stays where it is on the screen. It only goes to the txtX,txtY position when I insert a breakpoint in the code otherwise it just stays at it's location.

Comment: Where are you putting the breakpoint?

Comment: At the begining of  the SetWindowPosition function

Comment: Have you checked last error? `GetLastError()` function from WinAPI should give you a hint about what's going on. You should make use of your flag set in the attribute.

Comment: how do I set the flag, sorry I'm kinda new to the DLLImport in c#

Comment: Set the flag to true `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`   
Get the last error as suggested `int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();`  
Hint: The method SetWindowPos has an boolean return value for success `bool success = SetWindowPos();`

Comment: I just noticed something when I add to watch the 'SetWindowPos(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);' a weird message was written in the add watch error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'SetWindowPos' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @CreateAHero I'll try that right now and tell you the result

Comment: @CreateAHero I've tried the `int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();` and the `bool success = SetWindowPos();` with having the breakpoint it's err =0 and success = true, but without the break point I got err = 1400 and success = false.

Comment: Ok, try to define `IntPtr hWnd = null;` outside of your method.

Comment: @user9223088 As it reads on the documentation page _ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE = 1400 (0x578)_ so I'm guessing your window handle is wrong

Comment: @CreatAHero I tried `IntPtr hWnd = null;` outside of the method but still the same err = 1400

Comment: Is it possible that this is a race condition, where without the breakpoint, this code runs before the window is properly initialized, but with the breakpoint, the window has enough time get set up properly?

Comment: @Bradley Uffner do u mean I need to use delegates because I have delegates for the buttons and labels and all.

Comment: I've tried `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);` at the beginning of `SetWindowPosition` method and it seems to fix the problem but is there a better way to fix this rather then using `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: I just tested your code, and it didn't need a breakpoint to move the windows from it's position to the position set in the code.

Comment: @PaulKaram That sounds interesting did u add anything to the code! It seems to work with the `Thread.Sleep(50)` but I was aiming for something different from thread.sleep because that just stops the whole application and I don't want that to happen, any ideas.

Comment: @user9223088 I didn't add anything. Just created a new empty windows project, added one button to the form, and added your code. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @PaulKaram did you add the `Thread.Sleep(50)` at the beginning of the `SetWindowPosition` because that was the only way that made it work for me without a break point. I'm trying to search for some kind of delay that I can use other then  `Thread.Sleep(50)`

Comment: @user9223088 Nope. Didn't need it.

Comment: @PaulKaram That's strange in my case I do need to put either a breakpoint or `Thread.Sleep` !!

Comment: Can you try it with an empty project? Or is it already an empty project? Do you have any other running thread? Any errors?

Comment: @PaulKaram it is an empty project and no there aren't any other threads running.